# How to show content with jQuery UI Slider?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Example: [image: Example]

I have a problem about how to show content with jQuery UI Slider on each step and remove previous content.

```
                      <div id="range-slider"></div> <!-- ui jquery range slider-->

                        <!-- block of content -->
                        <div class="items">

                            <!-- first-block -->
                            <div class="slider-content">
                                <span>lorem ipsum:</span>
                                <span class="price">30 000</span>
                            </div>

                            <!-- second-block -->
                            <div class="slider-content">
                                <span>lorem ipsum:</span>
                                <span class="price">30 000</span>
                            </div>

                        </div>

 $("#range-slider").slider({
        max: 20,
        min: 4,
        step: 4,
        change: function (event, ui) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your css?

Comment: You can use `ui.value` in `change` event. Refer this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/9Lttr6ro/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `change` function, following this code

```
$('.items div').removeClass('active');
$('.items div:nth-child(' + ui.value / $(this).slider("option", "step") + ')').addClass('active');
```

and add `slide` callback

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $('.items div').removeClass('active');
    $('.items div:nth-child(' + ui.value / $(this).slider("option", "step") + ')').addClass('active');  
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/zfp3zq8p/)

style `#range-slider`, `ui-slider-range`, `ui-slider-handle`, `ui-state-active`, `ui-state-hover`